# php file child theme directory not overriding parent theme php file

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, themes

I am trying to customize the html in theme/woocommerce/layout-products/grid.php,
I have copied the file from parent theme to theme-child/woocommerce/layout-products/grid.php but without any effects. 
From the answers I found here I understand that sometimes copying the php file works, sometimes not? 
I also tried the require_once for this file but this breaks the whole WordPress.
How can I customize the product grid html?

Answer (score -1):

That **layout-products** folder is not a folder from Woocommerce templates. This folder is a custom folder created by the theme you are using. 
Try checking out how that template is loaded and see if it can be overriden.